# Why is AT TIME ZONE nondeterministic?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, timezone

SQL Server 2016's [`AT TIME ZONE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt612795.aspx) appears to be nondeterministic. However, I haven't been able to find documentation officially stating this or giving a rationale as to the reasoning behind it.

Why is `AT TIME ZONE` nondeterministic?

#### Example Showing Non-Determinism

Executing:

```
CREATE TABLE Test (
    LegacyTimestamp DATETIME,
    Timestamp AS LegacyTimestamp AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time' PERSISTED
);
```

Returns the following error:

```
Msg 4936, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Computed column 'Timestamp' in table 'Test' cannot be persisted because the column is non-deterministic.
```

Comment: Three words.  Daylight Savings Time.

Comment: Welcome to the nightmare known as time. I almost wish it was mandatory when you store time, you also stored what time zone as well. I would save so much in headache medication.

Comment: Just created a [Microsoft Connect item](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback/Details/3104516) asking for documentation to be updated to reflect 'AT TIME ZONE's non-determinism.

Answer (score 22):

`AT TIME ZONE` [employs some logic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt612795.aspx#Anchor_4) to calculate Daylight Savings Time. DST offset values are not immutable (they are subject to change via [windows updates](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/22803/daylight-saving-time)) and are contained externally in the Windows registry, so therefor the `AT TIME ZONE` function cannot be deterministic since it is relying on external data.

Similarly, this is why `sys.time_zone_info` is a view and not a static reference table, it needs to be calculated depending on the registry values which have the most up to date timezone information.

Comment: But it's shouldn't it be calculated in reference to the date being converted? If it's non-deterministic, it's because the rule of what day daylight savings starts on may change in the future, as it did in 2009.

Comment: @Random832 Right! I skipped over some the details for this, I've updated to be more clear.

Comment: @Random832, consider no only past dates but future dates. If a future date is stored based on the time change rules that exist today the value will become invalid if rules change between now and then,

Comment: John: this is good info, but wouldn't it be more technically accurate to rearrange this a little to say that the actual reason that it is non-deterministic is merely due to the external dependency on getting the info from the registry? Sure, _why_ it has to get the info from there as opposed to being hard-coded into the app code (i.e. the root cause) is mostly due to _how frequently_ the DST rules change, _and_ the fact that new Time Zones can be introduced, but that is really secondary, right? But regardless of the "why", any external dependency should make any function non-deterministic.

Comment: @srutzky attempted to clean up a bit.

Comment: Awesome! FYI, I found some rather interesting info here -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database -- that seems to be one of the few documents (at least that I could find so far) that indicate that DST is not the only thing to change. From what I can tell from looking at the **C:\Windows\Globalization\Time Zone\timezones.xml** file, even the base offsets can change over time, though less frequently since 1970, I guess. +1 :-)  (had to repost this as the link had a bad character in it)

Answer (score 1):

I have added AT TIME ZONE to the nondeterministic list on the Deterministic and Nondeterministic topic, and in the topic AT TIME ZONE, I added:
Since some information (such as timezone rules) is maintained outside of SQL Server and are subject to occasional change, the AT TIME ZONE function is classed as nondeterministic.
Thank you for bringing this up.
Rick Byham, SQL Server Books Online.

Comment: This should be a comment rather than an answer !